# Minipage and align environment

Tags: align, minipage, alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
  blablablablablablablablablablablabla

  I want this line at the end of the minipage.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
  \begin{align*}
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've played around with [t] [h] [c] arguments of minipage environment, but haven't achieved the desired result.

1. I want equations to be on the top of minipage on the same horizontal line with blablabla.
2. I want the last text line inside the minipage to be at the bottom of minipage. Of course, I can do that using vspace{3cm}, but maybe there is a way without manual calculations how many cm vspace should do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hope `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip` from the package `mathtools` may helps you...Usage is `\begin{align*}
\SwapAboveDisplaySkip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some knowledge of low level box management…

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

% take care of the interline spacing
\edef\theprevdepth{\the\prevdepth}\nointerlineskip
% let's do some measuring
\sbox0{$
  \begin{aligned}[b]
    x &= y + z\\
    x &= y + z\\
    x &= y + z\\
    x &= y + z\\
    x &= y + z
  \end{aligned}
$}%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht0][s]{\dimexpr0.9\textwidth-\wd0}
\prevdepth=\theprevdepth
blablablablablablablablablablablabla

\vfill

I want this line at the end of the minipage.
\end{minipage}\hfill\usebox{0}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
  blablablablablablablablablablablabla

  I want this line at the end of the minipage.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
  \begin{align*}
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: for an alignment of the first sentence at the top of the minipage, and of the last sentence at bottom, here is a hack:

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
  blablablablablablablablablablablabla

  I want this line at the end of the minipage.\rule{0pt}{4.75\baselineskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering $ \begin{aligned}[b]
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z\\
      x &= y + z
  \end{aligned} $
\end{minipage}

\blindtext
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, but I want blalblabla at the top (next to first x = y + z)

Comment: @Allok: I've added a hack to obtain the alignment you'd like. Please see whether it is OK for you .

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand right, that we need manually calculate the right value (4.75\baselineskip) for \rule? Is there an automatic way?

Comment: Yes. I first tried with 4 \baselineskip, which was not enough, and 5 were too much.  If you don't care for an approximate alignment at the top, you can use `\dimexpr4\baselineskip+4\jot`,  but it may be ruined by the real contents of each equation (in case of fractions, roots and so on). Personally, I know  no automatic way, but some TeX guru might have a code for that.

Comment: @Allok: Thanks for the edit!